# How to Condition check like i< J in for loop kotlin

Tags: for-loop, kotlin

Need to know how to write a condition check inside a for loop

for example Kotlin

```
class StarTriangle { 

public static void main(String[] args)  { 
   int i,j,k; for(i=1; i<=5; i++) { 
   for(j=4; j>=i; j--) { 
      System.out.print(" "); 
   } 
   for(k=1; k<=(2*i-1); k++) {
      System.out.print("*"); 
   }
   System.out.println(""); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use iterator with for loop like this:

change `for(i=1; i<=5; i++)` to `for(i in 1..5)`

```
var i=0
var j=0
var k=0
for(i in 1..5) {
    for(j in 4 downTo i) { 
        print(" ")
    }
    for(k in 1..(2*i-1)) { 
        print("*")
    } 
    println("")
}
```

output,

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using while instead of for.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var i: Int
    var j: Int
    var k: Int
    i = 1
    while (i <= 5) {
        j = 4
        while (j >= i) {
            print(" ")
            j--
        }
        k = 1
        while (k <= 2 * i - 1) {
            print("*")
            k++
        }
        println("")
        i++
    }
}
```

Output :

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the other answers that you can also use `repeat` function:

```
for (i in 1..5) {
    repeat(5 - i) { print(" ") }
    repeat(2 * i - 1) { print("*") }
    println()
}
```